# Deploying mobile web in titanium studio shows nothing

Tags: titanium

I'm a newbie to titanium studio and i like mobile programming.
When creating a new project on titanium, i have selected mobile web and android.
The project runs well on android phone but when deploying for web it doesn't show anything.
Am i missing something? please help

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is an integrated server running your apps in browser. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Deploying_and_Distributing_Mobile_Web_Apps

Otherwise Titianium deploys your app to a given location. In this case I think you need to access it by yourself in browser.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Mobile_Web

You may also check: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Mobile_Web_Platform_Overview